# C nested char array change in function with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-call

I have a array and ı want to change with pointers but array is nested char array like char array[][] how can i change the array in function.

```
char MAP[ROW][COLUMN] = {
    "00000000000000000000",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "0                  0",
    "00000000000000000000",
};

for (int y = 0; y < ROW; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x< COLUMN; x++)
    {
        if (MAP[y][x] != '0')
        {
            MAP[y][x] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

I want the change this array in function.

Comment: First of all you need to pass the array to the function. Then you just use it as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the function either like

```
void change( char MAP[][COLUMN], int row )
{
    for (int y = 0; y < row; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x< COLUMN; x++)
        {
            if (MAP[y][x] != '0')
            {
                MAP[y][x] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
change( MAP, ROW );
```

And in this case at least the identifier `COLUMN` must be defined before the function declaration.

Or if your compiler supports variable length array when

```
void change( int row, int column, char MAP[][column] )
{
    for (int y = 0; y < row; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x< column; x++)
        {
            if (MAP[y][x] != '0')
            {
                MAP[y][x] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
change( ROW, COLUMN, MAP );
```